# How to make a hamburger menu button on mobile web?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a hamburger menu button on a navbar inside a mobile web. This is my first time to build mobile web. And this code only show a huge square kind button instead of a nice hamburger menu. Please help.

```
<nav class="navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand ui-link" onclick="window.location.href='/'"href</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#popup">
      <span class="text">Menu</span>
      <span class="icon-bars">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: within 
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a|b">
....
</div>
</body

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but one thing you are missing in your "hamburger menu" is a color for the "bars".

So if you just add for example a `background-color` to your `icon-bar` elements it will show the hamburger menu.

```
.icon-bar {
  background-color: black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/L4f55sgz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just embed this code where you want a hamburger menu and it will automatically display the menu:

```html
<svg>
   <path fill="black" d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you explain your code?  It can help the OP figure out how to use it and where.

Comment: you can just embedd it where you want to use it and a hamburger menu will come this will work in html

Comment: @LakshayaRaj SVG codes are usually unexplainable because we mention the path, which is stored in XML format.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>A humburger icon:</p>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you used a `span` instead of a `div`, which has made all the difference, because `span` is an inline element and `div` is a block level element.

Using `div`s with some CSS as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66141228/14900600) answer can help, but there are many ways through it.

You can use SVG, if you want a simple icon. It has been mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164212/how-to-make-a-hamburger-menu-button-on-mobile-web/66141228#66141228) answer, but I'll still quote it:

```html
<svg>
   <path fill="black" d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"></path>
</svg>
```

You can also create an animated icon, like this:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Hope I could help